# DAX - How to use DATESBETWEEN in SWITCH function

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax

I am having a bit of tough time wrapping my head around this. I have a column based on response time in hours and our company's SLA (service level agreement) is that all incoming inquires should be answered within 2 days (the response time in hours is total hours spent on responding to inquiry).

The problem is that our company operates with winter time (7 h 45 min) and summer time (7 h). My dataset consist both and I want Power BI to differietiate winter and summer time when I try to compute SLA. In winter time 1 working day = 7 h 45 min and in summer time = 7 h. I have just used the average of summer/winter time = 7 h 30 min. The SLA column consist 3 data types, "Innen en arbeidsdag", "Innen to arbeidsdager" and "over 2 arbeidsdager".

I have used the following syntax:

SLA = SWITCH(TRUE(),Response time in hours>15, "Over to arbeidsdager", esponse time in hours>7.5, "Innen to arbeidsdager", Response time in hours<=7.5, "Innen en arbeidsdag")

How can I use DATESBETWEEN in this syntax to tell Power BI that Response Time YTD column from 15th May to 15th September is summer time, Working day = 7 h?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, I wouldn't use DATESBETWEEN. If you want to input dates directly to logically categorize your work seasons, try this:

```
SWITCH(TRUE()
    ,'Date'[Date] >= DATE(2022,5,15)
        && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE(2022,9,15)
    ,7
    ,BLANK()--You can carry on with logic for other seasons
)
```

I am using this syntax on a date table, but you can do this with any table that has a date column.

Comment: I tried to reply here, but gave an answer to my post instead. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

My dataset is called 'Masterdata' and my columns looks like this:

```
Svartid i t                SLA   
   6,12             Innen en arbeidsdag   
   11,73            Innen to arbeidsdager  
   20,42            Over to arbeidsdager   
    1,07            Innen en arbeidsdag    
    etc                    etc
```

My syntax so far:

```
SLA = SWITCH(TRUE(),Masterdata[Svartid i t]>15, "Over to arbeidsdager", Masterdata[Svartid i t]>7.5, "Innen to arbeidsdager", Masterdata[Svartid i t]<=7.5, "Innen en arbeidsdag")
```

So how can implement

```
SWITCH(TRUE(),'Date'[Date] >= DATE(2022,5,15) && 'Date'[Date] <= DATE(2022,9,15),7,BLANK()
```

In my syntax?